# Selecting the second (middle) row between MIN & MAX values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
TicketNumber           CallDate
--------------------------------------------
101                    10/09/2015 3:15:43 PM
101                    10/09/2015 3:45:43 PM
101                    11/19/2015 2:23:09 PM
```

I want to select the min date, the middle date and the max date. It is easy to get the first and last dates using MIN and MAX. But how to SELECT (get) the second date?

```
SELECT 
    TicketNumber
    , MIN(CallDate) CallDate1
    , MAX(CallDate) CallDate3
    , COUNT(TicketNumber) [Count]
FROM Table1
WHERE -(conditions)-
GROUP BY TicketNumber
HAVING COUNT(TicketNumber)=3
```

Between `MIN` & `MAX` dates in the `SELECT` statement I want the **second row date.**

The expected output should be:

```
TicketNumber   CallDate1              CallDate2             CallDate3                Count
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101            10/9/2015 3:15:43 PM  10/9/2015 3:45:43 PM   11/19/2015 2:23:09 PM    3
```

Comment: Is there only one row inbetween? How do you know?

Comment: Yes Im only selecting where Ticket COUNT=3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible variant. At first number and count all rows, then filter only those `TicketNumbers` that have three tickets and `PIVOT` result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d6954dd72e53b9015d2a6e6546058f8/10/0)

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Tickets TABLE (TicketNumber int, CallDate datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO @Tickets (TicketNumber, CallDate) VALUES
(101, '2015-10-09 03:15:43'),
(101, '2015-10-09 03:45:43'),
(101, '2015-11-19 02:23:09'),

(102, '2015-11-20 02:23:09'),
(102, '2015-11-19 02:23:09'),
(102, '2015-11-21 02:23:09'),

(103, '2015-11-10 02:23:09'),
(103, '2015-11-19 02:23:09'),

(104, '2015-11-11 02:23:09'),
(104, '2015-11-01 02:23:09'),
(104, '2015-11-21 02:23:09'),
(104, '2015-11-30 02:23:09');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        TicketNumber
        ,CallDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TicketNumber ORDER BY CallDate) AS rn
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TicketNumber) AS cnt
    FROM
        @Tickets AS T
)
SELECT
    P.TicketNumber
    ,[1] AS CallDate1
    ,[2] AS CallDate2
    ,[3] AS CallDate3
    ,cnt
FROM
    CTE
    PIVOT (MIN(CTE.CallDate) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS P
WHERE cnt = 3
ORDER BY P.TicketNumber;
```

**Result**

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| TicketNumber |      CallDate1      |      CallDate2      |      CallDate3      | cnt |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
|          101 | 2015-10-09 03:15:43 | 2015-10-09 03:45:43 | 2015-11-19 02:23:09 |   3 |
|          102 | 2015-11-19 02:23:09 | 2015-11-20 02:23:09 | 2015-11-21 02:23:09 |   3 |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using table `JOINS`.

```
SELECT t1.TicketNumber, t2.CallDate1, t1.CallDate AS CallDate2, t2.CallDate3, t2.Count
FROM tickets AS t1 
JOIN (
     SELECT TicketNumber, MIN(CallDate) AS CallDate1, MAX(CallDate) AS CallDate3,
     COUNT(TicketNumber) AS Count
     FROM tickets
     GROUP BY TicketNumber
     HAVING COUNT(TicketNumber)=3
    ) AS t2
ON t1.TicketNumber = t2.TicketNumber
WHERE t1.CallDate > t2.CallDate1
AND t1.CallDate < t2.CallDate3
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18677/8)**